Is there a Greek manuscript containing the definite article preceding the name of Jesus (ὁ Ἰησοῦς) in John 14:6?
I've been trying to find a Greek manuscript that actually includes the definite article with the name Jesus (ὁ Ἰησοῦς) in John 14:6. Codex Sinaiticus does not contain the article:
I've been led to believe there are extant texts that include the article.

Related, possible duplicate : John 14:5-9 Greek article with name 'Jesus'

Thanks Nigel — I actually scanned this article but couldn't find any specific manuscripts in the thread which is what I hunting for. My Nestle-Aland Novum Testamentum Graece leads me to believe there are a handful of texts somewhere out there.

The critical apparatus of NA28 has the following information concerning John 14:6 and the list of MSS that have or have not the article "ho" before "Jesus":

Those that OMIT the article: P66, Codex Sinaiticus (= "Aleph" 01), C04 Ephraemi Recscriptus, L019
Those that INCLUDE the article: A02, B03, C04(as corrected by the third hand), D05, K017, N022, Q026, W032, 036, 037, 038, 044, f1, F13, 33, 565, 579, 700, 892, 1241, 1424, etc.

Here is an image of the John 14:6 with "the Jesus" highlighted from Codex Vaticanus.  Note the Nomina Sacra, "IC" for "Jesus"

Thus, while plenty of MSS include the article, a few of the very earliest omit it.  Thus, in the NA28/UBS the article is placed in singular square brackets.

Thanks Dottard. By the way, where were you able to grab that very legible snapshot of John? I landed on the Vatican Library's digitized version but trying to decipher it was exasperating.

@edhuff - see https://www.csntm.org/ for thousands of imaged MSS including Vaticanus and many others

Dottard, Is there a way to narrow the search on csnt.org? I'm assuming I'll need a userid and password. BTW, what a great resource.

@edhuff - that would help but is not essential - I do not have one.  Just search for vaticanus MSS and the image will turn up in CSNTM.  Then you will notice at the bottom of the page the references for the text appears.
